# What happens subtracting (char *)a - (char *)0

Tags: c, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

In c language. What happens when we subtract Null pointer from char *

```
int i = (char *)a - (char *)0;
```

Comment: I think the result is undefined.

Comment: What is `a` defined as?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can we subtract NULL pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55747642/can-we-subtract-null-pointers)

Comment: @phuclv No. But I found the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39836849/5144634

Answer (score 1):

Pointer difference is defined only for two pointers that both point into or just past the end of the same array (where a pointer to a non-array object is considered as if it were a pointer to a one-element array).  By definition, a null pointer does not point to any object, therefore no pointer difference involving a null pointer has defined behavior.  Not even the difference between two null pointers.